# UIButton on a subview not responding to touch up inside events

Tags: ios

I have checked to make sure the button is on top and that the proper outlets are connected.
There is a break point set in the IBAction method that is to be called and it is not getting called when I press the UIButton. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the source code that you are having the problem with?

Comment: Is that button displayed within the bounds of its superview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake, I did a po on the subviews and it was behind a view.
This would explain why it was not getting touch events.

Answer (score 4):

Check to make sure the view that this button is inside has User Interaction Enabled.

Comment: Yep it is. Hmm starting to become puzzling.

Comment: On the container Turn on ClipSubviews and see if the button disappears